# Finding better weapons?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Now I only have shotguns and hunting rifles but there are so many guns that I don't have. Each day I send out 2 for 12 hours. These two explorers bring back the same sort of guns back, now I have one explorer and that one has been out for 19 hours and still haven't found anything but clothes and hunting rifles!

How can I find good weapons?
I only send out dwellers with high luck and endurance but I never find anything good.

Answer (score 5):

You need to send them out for longer time. By time you can skill your dwellers. Send them to the gym, casino etc. If their S.P.E.C.I.A.L values raise, you'll have a better chance to live longer. Just a hint, before sending a lvl 1 dweller out, put him in a fully equipped reactor or something. He will level up fast as you collect the energy.

If he gets a higher level he will have more life. If he had level 10 or 20 it's okay for his first run in the badlands.

Let him go with the maximum of stimpacks (25) and around 14-15 rad-away.
Don't panic, if something is left over at the end, it will be added back to your stock.

Give him your best gun and your best outfit. If he survive 18/19 hours you'll have a good chance for getting better guns. My current dweller is on it's tour for around 38 hours and he has a machine pistol, a grenade launcher and a flamethrower (18-25 dmg).

Hopefully this will help you to get better weapons. :-)

Comment: Just by the way. I've just found a Gauss canon after 1 day and 20 hours expedition.

Comment: What were the stats of the guys who got flamethrower and gauss? I got people running for 25 hours and basically the best thing I got were +3 suits and 8-9 dmg guns. Do I have to send them for a longer time, or does special stats matter more?

Answer (score -1):

If you have enough dwellers, the best method of finding rare weapons is to build a Game Room and train your dwellers' Luck. Luck is (as far as I know) specifically for sending dwellers into the badlands, and will greatly increase your chances of finding better weapons/outfits. Hope this helps!

Comment: Luck improves the number of caps found, but doesn't affect the type of equipment dropped. The longer you are out, the better stuff you find.

Answer (score -1):

The more you explore, the better the Loot. You might get a Legendary after some weeks.
*Also note that after 30 Days ± 15 Minutes, you will have a special encounter. The Loot is an almost-guaranteed Legendary.*

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: It's not realistic to stay out more than 3 or 4 days without some form of cheating.

Comment: Under normal gameplay, your explorer can't stay out that long.  I just had one guy turn around only after 1d 12 hours because he picked up tons of low end garbage.